# solidity cannot access member variable from another contract on private chain, works fine on remix javascript vm

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, go-ethereum

I have the following solidity code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Parent {
    uint public childCount;
    Child[] public children;

    function makeChild(string name) external {
        children.push(new Child(address(this), childCount, name));
        childCount++;
    }

    function renameChild(uint index, string newName) external {
        require(address(children[index]) != 0);
        Child thisChild = Child(address(children[index]));
        if (thisChild.isUpdated()) {
            thisChild.rename(newName);
        }
    }
}

contract Child {
    address parentAddress;
    uint index;
    string public name;
    bool public isUpdated;

    constructor(address parent, uint _index, string _name) public {
        parentAddress = parent;
        index = _index;
        name = _name;
        isUpdated = false;
    }

    function rename(string newName) external {
        name = newName;
    }

    function renameViaParent(string updateName) external {
        isUpdated = true;
        Parent(parentAddress).renameChild(index, updateName);
    }
}
```

I have been testing this code via [Remix Solidity IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org). When I run in Javascript VM, I can create a child from parentInstance.makeChild("childName") and rename it using childInstance.renameViaParent("newName").

However when I switch to an Ethereum private chain, i.e. Injected Web3, I can still create the child, but fail in renaming using childInstance.renameViaParent("newName"). It gives the message:

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? 
>   Invalid JSON RPC response: {"id":1830,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32603}}

I tried to remove `thisChild.isUpdated()` condition check in `renameChild(index, newName)` and the code ran fine in both JS VM and private Web3. This is why I believe accessing the member variable `isUpdated` of `Child` from `Parent` is causing the problem.

What is wrong here? Probably with my private chain set up? How is it different from the Javascript VM Remix is using?

I am using geth-linux-amd64-1.8.6-12683 to run my private chain.